# Redis Admin UI to display data

Tags: redis

I just started learning redis. Now I am looking for a very simple redis admin ui, to display the content (key-value) in some kind. I have already stored simple strings and also fetched them, but is there no way to display tho whole "database"?

I have found redsmin, but it is still in beta and I have been waiting for over a week to get any invitation.

Comment: Hello, the founder of Redsmin here, we are currently working on our public release and stopped our invite waves. You'll be able to access to Redsmin really soon, I promise!

Comment: That sounds great! October or Novemeber?

Comment: It'll be in October :)

Answer (score 1):

For start, call `KEYS *` to print out all of them.

Next, you can build your own basic viewer pretty much easily. Yes, it could be more sophisticated with many fancy things, but basic viewing of all keys (impractical in production probably but good for dev) would be easy.

Comment: I am using ServiceStack.Redis and trying to figure out all the methods. I got the keys, but still I would prefer a simple GUI.